# Parsing json in Bigquery, json_extract and jason_extract_scalar not working

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column called shopaddress which has the following content

> "{"storeId":"16301","city":"abccc","axdcCode":14917,"preferredDcs":[],"omniChannel":true,"clusterId":"16301 - ALxxxxxET TTK ROAD","allocationProfileName":"che1","hubType":"HubCS","lat":12.222,"lng":82.2539,"openTime":0,"closeTime":2400,"storeType":"Hub","distance":0,"radius":7,"coldChain":true,"considerInventory":true}"

The leading and trailing quotations included, like stated above both the standard json_extract functions aren't working, I experimented with trim and replace as well, trying to remove the leading and trailing " first and then replacing the slashes. But to no avail. Any hints will be very helpful.

Comment: Hi @Sruthi , Have you checked the [different functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#categories) of the standard extractors of JSON ? Let me know if this is helpful or not.

Answer (score 0):

This JSON schema does not have any nested fields so I'm assuming you'll only be extracting scalar values.

Try JSON_VALUE instead of JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR and JSON_QUERY instead of JSON_EXTRACT

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(TRIM(shopaddress, '"'), '$.Field-Name')
FROM `table-Name`
```